# Euler product approximation of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

It is well-known that the Riemann zeta function can be approximated in the critical strip by a finite Dirichlet polynomial. More precisely,
$$
\zeta(\sigma+it) = \sum_{n \leq X} n^{-\sigma-it} + \frac{X^{1-\sigma-it}}{\sigma+it-1} + O ( X^{-\sigma})
$$
uniformly for all $X$ satisfying $2 \pi X / C \geq |t|$, where $C$ is a fixed constant greater than 1. (This is Theorem 4.11 in Titchmarsh's book). In particular this holds for $\sigma = 1/2$.

Question: is there a similar (simple) approximation of zeta by a finite Euler product?

Comment: PS: I want to avoid the large correction term of order $\approx X^{1-\sigma}$. This large correction term corresponds to the large number of summands in the Dirichlet polynomial. The idea is that an Euler product approximation would probably be "sparse" when written as a Dirichlet polynomial, thus not requiring this large correction term.

Answer (score 9):

See [Finite Euler products and the Riemann Hypothesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3448) by S. M. Gonek (2007):

> We show that if the Riemann Hypothesis is true, then in a region
>   containing most of the right-half of the critical strip, the Riemann
>   zeta-function $\zeta$ is well approximated by short $X$-term truncations $\zeta_X$ of its Euler
>   product. Conversely, if the approximation by products is good in this
>   region, the zeta-function has at most finitely many zeros in it.

[image]

This approximation also provides insight into why the zeroes on the critical line "repel", in the sense of level repulsion in the Gaussian Unitary Ensemble.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this paper, but I cannot make much sense out of it. What's the role of the function Z in their paper? Is it large, is it small?

Comment: PS: I should note that I am looking for unconditional results (without assuming RH).